# Description of a Stored Procedure. Listing Arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Is there any way of listing down all of the parameters necessary to invoke a stored procedure (with an Oracle DB)?

For instance, I have a function called x that someone else has developed and now I have to call it but I don't know which parameters x expects and which of them are mandatory or not.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the privileges granted, you can query [all_arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1014.htm#i1573843) or  [user_arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4278.htm#i1633235) or starting from 11g.r1 [dba_arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_3063.htm#I1023015) to list arguments and other arguments-related information of stored procedures:

Example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure ProcX(
  2    p_par1 in number,
  3    p_par2 in varchar2 default 'default',
  4    p_par3 out number
  5  )
  6  is
  7  begin
  8    null;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created

select t.object_name
     , t.argument_name
     , t.position
     , t.data_type
     , t.defaulted
     , t.in_out
  from user_arguments t
 where  t.object_name = 'PROCX'

Object_Name Argument_Name Position Data_Type Defaulted In_Out 
--------------------------------------------------------------
PROCX       P_PAR3        3        NUMBER    N         OUT 
PROCX       P_PAR2        2        VARCHAR2  Y         IN 
PROCX       P_PAR1        1        NUMBER    N         IN
```

Value `Y` in the `Defaulted` column indicates that the parameter `p_par2` has a default value thus optional.

Answer (score 0):

Even one can find subroutine arguments from `%_ARGUMENTS`-tables (as demonstrated by Nicholas) in many cases that's probably not enough (depending on the context/complexity of the domain). Instead you should have access to *a documented subroutine signature* either by documentation or by viewing the subroutine (documented) code in the database (the GUI tools like [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) and [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/) are great for that) or from version control system.

If your starting point really is:

> I have a function called x that someone else has developed and now I have to call it but I don't know which parameters x expects and which of them are mandatory or not.

And there is no documentation and you have no access to the source code then I doubt that information like:

```
Object_Name Argument_Name Position Data_Type Defaulted In_Out 
--------------------------------------------------------------
PROCX       P_PAR3        3        NUMBER    N         OUT 
PROCX       P_PAR2        2        VARCHAR2  Y         IN 
PROCX       P_PAR1        1        NUMBER    N         IN
```

doesn't help you much (even if arguments have more descriptive names) unless the function is "trivial".

For your sake I hope this is a one-time issue only - in all other scenarios your project is very likely going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged `plsqldeveloper`.

One of the great features of such a great product is to right click the method after finding it in the object browser. There are options for all manner of instant interrogation without writing any queries.